# Frequent json decoder error - decoder.py line 357, in raw_decode

Tags: python, json

I dont know a bit of python and below script is output of 6 hour google research. My task is very simple. Wanted to created a text file with movie information pulled from OMDB. I dumped all movie names in a text file and ran following script. Each time I run following script I get only 15-20 movie info but afterwards I get decoder error. When I rerun by removing the movie names for which I already got the info I again get 10-15 movie info! I am not expert in Python but everything below looks fine so not sure why I am getting this.

```
import json
import requests
import sys
import time

if(len(sys.argv) != 2):
    print("Please provide the movie file name as input arg. Ex " + sys.argv[0] + " movie_names.txt")
    print("Please note that in movie file each movie name should be on a new line")
else:
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        for line in f:
            json_obj_movie_detail = requests.get ("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=\"" + line.rstrip('\n') + "\"&apikey=$$$$$$$")
            j = json.loads( json_obj_movie_detail.content )
            if(j.get('Title')):
                print (j['Title']+ ";" , end='', flush=True)
            else:
                print (line.rstrip('\n') + ";" + "Could not find this movie!", end='', flush=True)

            if(j.get('Genre')):
                print (j['Genre']+ ";" , end='', flush=True)
            else:
                print ("null" + ";", end='', flush=True)

            if(j.get('Plot')):
                print (j['Plot']+ ";" , end='', flush=True)
            else:
                print ("null" + ";" , end='', flush=True)

            counter = 0

            if(j.get('Title')):
                for each_rating_source in j['Ratings']:
                    print (j['Ratings'][counter]['Source'] + ";", end='', flush=True)
                    print (j['Ratings'][counter]['Value'] + ";", end='', flush=True)
                    counter = counter + 1
            else:
                print ("null", end='', flush=True)

            print(" ")

    f.close()
```

would really appreciate help from Python / Json experts.

/********* Error *****/

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\peacedove\movie_detail.py", line 13, in <module>
    j = json.loads( json_obj_movie_detail.content )
  File "C:\Users\peacedove\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\peacedove\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\peacedove\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Are you sure the API provider (OMDB) does not have any limitations in order to avoid high traffic etc?

Comment: Thanks for help but I checked that already. They have limit of 1000 API requests in a day and i was well with in limit.